# Failed to access the WSDL at: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL. It failed with:

Tags: java, eclipse

```
enter code here
package org.ameen.syed;

import net.webservicex.GeoIP;
import net.webservicex.GeoIPService;
import net.webservicex.GeoIPServiceSoap;

public class Iplocation {

/**
 * @param args
  */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(args.length !=1){
 System.out.println("u need to pass ipaddress ");
 }

else{
String ipAddress = args[0];
GeoIPService ipservice =  new GeoIPService();
GeoIPServiceSoap geoIPServiceSoap = ipservice.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
GeoIP geoip = geoIPServiceSoap.getGeoIP(ipAddress);
System.out.println(geoip.getCountryName());
}
 }
}
```

i dont know what is the problem .. i am new to webservice programming .. please help what is the mistake ..

thank you ..

Comment: You forgot to post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

every thing is correct only but for some address like facebook.com , or some shared hosting web address-ip address if you ping ip address and pass value it wont work properly , but if you ping for google.com    and submit the address it will work fine